# How can be done this automatic?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Is there any way to do this automatically for all derived classes, that i don't have to create function applyPack for all nested classes.

This is piece of my code:

```
/** every class has registered id with this function */
template<typename T>
uint getID() {
    static uint id = registerClass<T>();
    return id;
}

class TemplatesPack {
public:
    template<typename T>
    typename T::Template get();
};

class Object {
public:
    virtual void applyPack(TemplatesPack *p) { this->setTemplate(p->get<Object>()); };
};

class Object2: public Object {
public:
    void applyPack(TemplatesPack *p) { this->setTemplate(p->get<Object2>()); };
};

class Object3: public Object  {
public:
    void applyPack(TemplatesPack *p) { this->setTemplate(p->get<Object3>()); };
};

class Object4: public Object2 {
public:
    void applyPack(TemplatesPack *p) { this->setTemplate(p->get<Object4>()); };
};
```

I've read something about type traits but **i don't want to have class Object templated**. Can be this done with c++ and templating some functions in class TemplatesPack or with c++0x? s

Comment: What are you really trying to do? I can't think of a use case where what you're attempting to do in this question is required. It may be possible that there is a better way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit:
changed the answer to make the Object untouched.

```
template<class T>
class Base<T> : public Object
{
public:
    virtual void applyPack(TemplatePack *p) { this->setTemplate(p->get<T>()); };
};

class Object2 : public Base<Object2>
{
    // ...
};
```

Edit: for the case of `Object4`, maybe the following will help:

```
template<class S, class D>
class Base<S, D> : public S
{
public:
    virtual void applyPack(TemplatePack *p) { this->setTemplate(p->get<D>()); };
};

class Object2 : public Base<Object, Object2> { /* ... */ };

class Object3 : public Base<Object, Object3> { /* ... */ };

class Object4 : public Base<Object2, Object4> { /* ... */ };
```

Comment: -1: The OP said he didn't want to template the class, and what's worse, this approach means that `Object2`, `Object3`, etc. will be in unrelated class hierarchies!

Comment: I know this, this is similar to type traits, but i don't want have templated Base class because i have class based on derived class of base, then i will have to template also this!!!

Comment: @Miro: didn't understand your last comment. Maybe you can give a more elaborate example? Having Object2 based on a template class doesn't necessary mean that the classes derived from Object2 must be templates.

Comment: @Miro: Huh? `Object`, `Object2`, et al. are still non-template classes.

Comment: Very funny :D, but now it's class Object4 very bad. It isn't derived on Object2 and the function is getting template with param Object4 not Object2

Comment: @Miro: it **is** actually derived from `Object2` (although indirectly), because of the following: `class Base<T> : public T`. The rest is just corrected.

Comment: Yes now it's two times derived on Base and rather i wrote pieco code extra. Object4 -> Base<Object2,Object4> -> Object2 -> Base<Object,Object2> :)

Comment: Yes--is it a problem? This is exactly what you asked for, otherwise the Object4 won't be possible to use as if it were Object2.

Comment: @Miro: You would need `setTemplate` to be virtual, though, if you overload it in the derived classes, or you'd need `dynamic_cast`, as in @Johannes' answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use virtual inheritance and the dominance rule, if you don't want to templatize `Base`

```
template<typename Derived, typename Base = void>
struct applyer : virtual applyer<Base, typename Base::base_type> {
  virtual void applyPack(TemplatesPack *p) { 
    dynamic_cast<Derived*>(this)->setTemplate(p->get<Derived>()); 
  };

  typedef Base base_type;
};

template<typename Derived>
struct applyer<Derived, void> {
  virtual void applyPack(TemplatesPack *p) { 
    dynamic_cast<Derived*>(this)->setTemplate(p->get<Derived>()); 
  };
};
```

Now you can do it as follows

```
class Object : virtual public applyer<Object> {

};

class Object2: public Object, virtual public applyer<Object2, Object> {

};

class Object3: public Object, virtual public applyer<Object3, Object>  {

};
```

The second argument respectively is the direct base class, which can be omitted if there is none. For instance if you derive from `Object3`, you need to do that as follows

```
class Object3_1: public Object3, virtual public applyer<Object3_1, Object3>  {

};
```

Comment: Will this cost some extra memory in every object?

Comment: And can i use this in more times derived classes like Object4?

Comment: @Miro you will need to test whether it uses any more memory. I have no idea. It works fine with Object4 (called "Object3_1" in my example because I wrote it before you amended your question).

Comment: Adding complexity, adding dynamic type checking, and moving the specification of type from the call to a distant inheritance list? Is this a joke? How about, u know, making `get` a virtual function, or adding an argument to it?

Comment: Yes dynamic type chceking would be very good, but i don't know how do this in c++ or c++0x.

Comment: @Alf I don't know what the big picture is that is to be solved here, neither I know what `setTemplate` is, whether it is repeated and defined differently in each class and such. The code already has virtual functions, and possible also uses dynamic_cast already. I can only propose code that solves the problem (and in this case, it solves it conveniently - you don't need to repeat constructors to forward and so on). The questioner has to decide whether the code fits into the bigger picture, obviously.

Comment: I need this: applyPack(PACK)->(CHOOSE TEMPLATE BASED ON TYPE)->(setTemplate - non virtual function - assign member and registers self as user of Template(not pack))->(applyTemplate(tmpl) - virtual function where every class configures self)

Comment: @Miro: Are you sure you need that? What is the "big picture" goal you're trying to achieve? Like I said in my comment to your question, you need to tell us what you're really trying to do because we might be able to come up with a better, less complicated solution.

Comment: The main is that applyTemplate have to be called with right object based on dynamically determined type

Comment: what i really would do is to keep repeating that one single virtual function in each derived class. srsly, it's really less work than all so far proposed solutions.

Comment: @Miro: Right, we already know that. What we really want to know is why you need to call `applyTemplate` "with right object based on dynamically determined type." To what end does `applyTemplate` fulfill?

Comment: yes, it be probably very easier and simplier, with better performance. But you've provided very nice solution to do this. +1

Comment: Will help that every class has generated ID with templated function: template<typename T> uint getID() { static uint id = registerNewClass<T>(); return id; }

Comment: Can i get this id in Base's constructor?

Comment: Simple, every constructor should get this id and store it in const public member variable. Function template<typename T> typename T::Template get() is getting right template based on T's id :), now i can modify this to get(uint type_ID) :)